# Statistic people base on role and status

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm now making an application uses neo4j as my database.
I have one class:

```
class Person
{
  public string Id{get;set;}
  public int Role{get;set;}
  public int Status {get;set;}
}
```

Now I have 50 nodes, 25 of them are :

```
{
  Id : <GUID>
  Role: 3,
  Status : 0
}
```

And the other 25 are :

```
{
  Id: <GUID>
  Role: 3,
  Status : 2
}
```

I want to statistic the people base on their role and status.
With those records above, I have:

**25 people have role 3 and status is 0**

**25 people have role 3 and status is 2**

I've tried this query :

```
MATCH (a:Person), (b:Person)
WHERE (a.Status = 0 AND a.Role = 3) OR (b.Status = 2 AND b.Role = 3)
RETURN COUNT(a), COUNT(b)
```

Instead of **25, 25**.

It gave me :    **6976,     6976**

I don't know what the problem is.

Can anyone help me please ?
Thank you.

P/S: I'm using graphenedb.

Comment: You need a "group by"- type function: there's a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731911/how-to-have-group-by-in-cypher-query-in-neo4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement builds a cross product of all person in your graph.

Try this instead

```
MATCH (p:Person)
RETURN p.Role, p.Status, count(*)
```

In Cypher there's no "group by". If you use an aggregation function like `count` aggregation is done automatically on the other expressions (here `p.Role` and `p.Status`).

Comment: Thank you , it returns :

3 2 25
\r\n
3 0 25

And I think, on my server, I'll use linq to group these results.

Thank you for helping me :)